# Ant build failed with compile failed after I replace a .class file in one dependency jar

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

I'm new to Ant and currently there is a new Java web application build with ant need to support, a web application depend on b web application and added it in lib folder as a JAR dependency, so if there are some update on b, then I need rebuild b and generate a new JAR, then replace a's dependency.

While just like I say, I change a little code in one Java file on b application and then compile it, then I unzip dependency b JAR to replace that class file and re-zip it as a JAR file. When I build it, error occurs and showed that compile failed.

These two java application based on JDK1.6, add i also check jar file's source code is JDK 1.6, so i use JDK 1.6 compile it `javac updatedJava.java`, one more thing is that, if i don't replace this class file, it can build successfully in Jenkins, while once i update that class file it will fail.

I'm really not familiar with Ant. Here is my application details and some error log:

Application architecture:

```html
A 
 |-src
 |-web 
     |- WEB-INFO
          |- web.xml
          |- lib
             |- B.jar
 |- webex-build.xml

B
  |- src
      |- updatedJar.java
  |- build
      |- classes
  |- target
      |- B.jar
```

A's ant build file:

```html
<project name="A" default="war" basedir="."> 
 
  <property file="../build.properties"/> 
 
  <property name="version" value="1.0"/> 
  <property name="dir.root" value="."/> 
  <echo>#####################################################################</echo> 
  <echo>#       Building ${ant.project.name} Version is ${version}</echo> 
  <echo>#####################################################################</echo> 
     
  <!--property name="WL_HOME" value="D:/bea" /--> 
  <property name="app.lib" value="web/WEB-INF/lib" /> 
  <property name="server.lib" value="${wl.home}/server/lib"/> 
  <property name="modules.lib" value="${bea.home}/modules" /> 
  <property name="configfile_env" value="web_message_${env}.properties" /> 
  <!-- set local properties for this build --> 
  <path id="lib.classpath"> 
      <fileset dir="${app.lib}">  
             <include name="*.jar"/>  
      </fileset> 
    <pathelement location="${modules.lib}/javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar"/> 
    <pathelement location="${server.lib}/ojdbc6.jar"/> 
  </path> 
<property name="build" value="build"/> 
<property name="src" value="src/java"/> 
<property name="config" value="src/configsrc/"/> 
<property name="srcjaxws" value="src/jaxwssource"/> 
<property name="adapter" value="src/adapter"/>
<property name="reports.junit.xml.dir" value="junit/reports"/>
<property name="project.test.java.dir" value="src/test"/>
<property name="project.target.dir" value="target"/>
 
  <target name="init"> 
    <tstamp/> 
    <delete dir="${build}"/> 
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/> 
  </target> 
 
  <target name="compile" depends="init"> 
    <mkdir dir="${build}/classes"/> 
    <javac destdir="${build}/classes" debug="on" includeantruntime="false"> 
      <src path="${srcjaxws}"/> 
      <src path="${src}"/>  
      <src path="${adapter}"/>
      <classpath refid="lib.classpath"/> 
      <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/> 
    </javac> 
      <copy todir="${build}/classes/" overwrite="true" preservelastmodified="true" failonerror="true" verbose="true" flatten="false"> 
          <fileset dir="${config}"/> 
      </copy> 
      <!--if> 
                  <isset property="env" /> 
                  <then> 
                      <echo>ENV is set as ${env}</echo> 
                      <copy tofile="${build}/classes/config/system/web_message.properties" file="${build}/classes/config/config_env/web_message_${env}.properties" overwrite="true" /> 
                  </then> 
                  <else> 
                      <echo>There is no env set, if you want to set, please use -Denv=dev/qa/devint/pp/prod</echo> 
                  </else> 
              </if--> 
  </target> 
 
  <target name="test" depends="compile">
   <echo message="Testing..."/>
     <delete dir="${project.target.dir}" />
   <delete dir="${reports.junit.xml.dir}" />
     <mkdir dir="${project.target.dir}" />
   <mkdir dir="${reports.junit.xml.dir}" />

   <javac destdir="${build}/classes" debug="true" includeantruntime="false">
    <src path="${project.test.java.dir}"/>
    <classpath>
     <path refid="lib.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
    <classpath path="${build}/classes" />
   </javac>

         <taskdef name="junit" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask">
             <classpath>
                 <path refid="lib.classpath"/>
             </classpath>
         </taskdef>
   
         <!-- Import the JaCoCo Ant Task -->
         <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
             <!-- Update the following line, or put the "jacocoant.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
             <classpath path="${app.lib}/jacocoant.jar" />
         </taskdef>
   
    <!-- Run your unit tests, adding the JaCoCo agent -->
            <jacoco:coverage destfile="${project.target.dir}/jacoco-unit.exec" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
             <junit fork="yes" failureProperty="test.failed">
                <classpath refid="lib.classpath" />
                <classpath location="${build}/classes" />
                <classpath location="${build}" />

     <formatter type="xml" />
                <batchtest todir="${reports.junit.xml.dir}">
                 <fileset dir="${build}/classes">
                    <include name="**/*Test.class" />
                 </fileset>
                </batchtest>
             </junit>
      </jacoco:coverage>    

   <echo message="Test completed..."/>
</target>
 
  <target name="war" depends="compile"> 
    <mkdir dir="${build}/wls10"/> 
    <wars classes-dir="${build}/classes" build-dir="${build}"/> 
  </target> 
 
  <macrodef name="wars"> 
    <attribute name="classes-dir"/> 
    <attribute name="build-dir"/> 
    <sequential> 
      <war-task classes-dir="@{classes-dir}" build-dir="@{build-dir}" generic="javaee5" appserver="wls10"/> 
    </sequential> 
  </macrodef> 
 
  <macrodef name="war-task"> 
    <attribute name="classes-dir"/> 
    <attribute name="build-dir"/> 
    <attribute name="generic"/> 
    <attribute name="appserver"/> 
    <sequential> 
      <war destfile="@{build-dir}/@{appserver}/WebexPFProxyWS.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml"> 
        <classes dir="@{classes-dir}"></classes> 
        <webinf dir="web/WEB-INF" includes="web*.xm*"/> 
         
        <manifest></manifest> 
        <lib dir="${app.lib}"> 
            <include name="*.jar"/> 
        </lib> 
        
       <webinf dir="web/WEB-INF" includes="wsdl/**"/> 
        
       <fileset dir="web"> 
            <include name="**/*.jsp"/> 
        </fileset> 
        
        
      </war> 
    </sequential> 
  </macrodef> 
 
</project>
```

Error log in Jenkins when execute ant build:

line 41 is `<javac destdir="${build}/classes" debug="on" includeantruntime="false">` in above xml.

```html
[exec] [javac] XMLSerializer serializer = getXMLSerializer(writer, null);
[exec] [javac] ^
[exec] [javac] Note: Some input files additionally use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[exec] [javac] 100 errors
[exec] [javac] 116 warnings
[exec] 
[exec] BUILD FAILED
[exec] /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/java/A/webex-build.xml:41: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
[exec] 
[exec] Total time: 3 seconds

BUILD FAILED
/apps/dftjenkins/JENKINS_HOME_NODES/selfservices-build-scripts-stash/Proxy/build_ht.xml:149: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/apps/dftjenkins/JENKINS_HOME_NODES/selfservices-build-scripts-stash/Common/build_process.xml:517: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/apps/dftjenkins/JENKINS_HOME_NODES/selfservices-build-scripts-stash/Common/build_common.xml:179: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/apps/dftjenkins/JENKINS_HOME_NODES/selfservices-build-scripts-stash/Common/build_common.xml:182: exec returned: 1

Total time: 7 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Running post build processes
```

Answer (score 0):

when there's an invalid jar on the classpath, it is silently ignored. Given that you get a TON of build errors, it sounds like that's happening: Your code depends on the classes in that jar and that jar effectively disappeared because it is invalid.

Especially on early java versions, 'a jar is just a zip file' is not really true: Whilst unzip can succesfully unzip a jar, any old zip file you produce with a 'zip' tool is not neccessarily a valid jar.

I'd start by using the jar tool (and not zip) to add/replace the class file.

Comment: Hi @rzwitserloot, as you said, what tool u used to do that, any  suggestion?  thanks

Comment: 'jar'. It's next to javac.